# get firebase keys from snapshot not working

Tags: javascript, json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this in my firebase DB:

```
    {
  "vehicles" : {
    "fz20tqpxUChOM98fNUYGQhtZ83" : {
      "amount" : 31,
      "timeStamp" : "2017-07-18T20:31:34Z"
    },
    "sw30tqpxUChOM98fNUrGQhtk33" : {
      "amount" : 45,
      "timeStamp" : "2017-07-18T20:31:34Z"
    }
  }
```

I am using `.on` to get a snapshot of the data:

```
  var ref = database.ref('vehicles');
  ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {

    var obj = snapshot.val();
    for (var key in obj){

        console.log(obj);//prints my obj
        console.log(obj.key);//prints 'undefind' both times (why??)
        console.log(obj.fz20tqpxUChOM98fNUYGQhtZ83);//prints data



        if ('fz20tqpxUChOM98fNUYGQhtZ83' === key) {//Just for testing
          console.log("IT IS ===");                //my 'key' is equal to 
                                                   //the hardcoded key 
        } else {
          console.log("NOT ===");
        }

    }
  });
```

When I `console.log(obj.key);` I get `undefined` for both keys. However when I run `console.log(obj.fz20tqpxUChOM98fNUYGQhtZ83);` I get my data, obviously I can't hard code my key in there, so WHY is it not printing when I ask it too???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.key` would only work if there were a key in the object literally called `key`, like this:

```
{
    key: "foo"
}
```

What you want is `obj[key]`, which will look up the value of the key based on a dictionary lookup of the variable value instead of a literal reference.

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb.. Better than not knowing the answer for another 4 hours.